# Convert a document file to pdf in c# web api

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api2

I am saving some data into a table. In the table i have a column called AttachedDocumentNo which would be a pdf file. Ok here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tblRequirementType(
    [pkId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [szDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [iRequirementTypeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [szRequirementNumber] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [szRequirementIssuer] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [szOrganization] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [dIssuedate] [datetime] NULL,
    [dExpirydate] [datetime] NULL,
    [szSignedBy] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [szAttachedDocumentNo] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dStampdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [szSubject] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [iApplicationDetailsId] [bigint] NULL,
    [iEmpId] [bigint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblRequirementType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [pkId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRequirementType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRequirementType_iRequirementTypeId]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [iRequirementTypeId]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRequirementType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRequirementType_szSubject]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [szSubject]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRequirementType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRequirementType_iAppId]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [iApplicationDetailsId]
    GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRequirementType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRequirementType_iEmpId]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [iEmpId]
   GO
```

So I created a web api service to post data into the table.
The following is my API class:

```
    [Route("PostRequirementTypeProcessing")]
    public IEnumerable<NPAAddRequirementTypeProcessing> PostRequirementTypeProcessing(mdlAddAddRequirementTypeProcessing requTypeProcess)
    {
        mdlAddAddRequirementTypeProcessing rTyeProcessing = new mdlAddAddRequirementTypeProcessing(); 

        HttpFileCollection hfc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

        //Filename = requTypeProcess.szSubject;
        rTyeProcessing.szDescription = requTypeProcess.szDescription;
        rTyeProcessing.iRequirementTypeId = requTypeProcess.iRequirementTypeId;
        rTyeProcessing.szRequirementNumber = requTypeProcess.szRequirementNumber;
        rTyeProcessing.szRequirementIssuer = requTypeProcess.szRequirementIssuer;
        rTyeProcessing.szOrganization = requTypeProcess.szOrganization;
        rTyeProcessing.dIssuedate = requTypeProcess.dIssuedate;
        rTyeProcessing.dExpirydate = requTypeProcess.dExpirydate;
        rTyeProcessing.szSignedBy = requTypeProcess.szSignedBy;
        rTyeProcessing.szAttachedDocumentNo = requTypeProcess.szAttachedDocumentNo;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rTyeProcessing.szAttachedDocumentNo))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            UploadFiles(hfc);
        }
        rTyeProcessing.szSubject = requTypeProcess.szSubject;
        rTyeProcessing.iApplicationDetailsId = requTypeProcess.iApplicationDetailsId;
        rTyeProcessing.iEmpId = requTypeProcess.iEmpId;

        NPAEntities context = new NPAEntities();
        Log.Debug("PostRequirementTypeProcessing Request traced");

        var newRTP = context.NPAAddRequirementTypeProcessing(requTypeProcess.szDescription, requTypeProcess.iRequirementTypeId, 
                                    requTypeProcess.szRequirementNumber, requTypeProcess.szRequirementIssuer, requTypeProcess.szOrganization, 
                                    requTypeProcess.dIssuedate, requTypeProcess.dExpirydate, requTypeProcess.szSignedBy, 
                                    requTypeProcess.szAttachedDocumentNo, requTypeProcess.szSubject, requTypeProcess.iApplicationDetailsId, 
                                    requTypeProcess.iEmpId);

        return newRTP.ToList();
    }
```

What i want to do is that, when saving into the database, it should save everything but the szAttachedDocumentNo should be saved as pdf file in its column.

I did search on the internet and got a piece of code and tried to transformed it to my need:

```
    public string UploadFiles(HttpFileCollection strDocPath)
    {
        int iUploadedCnt = 0;

        // DEFINE THE PATH WHERE WE WANT TO SAVE THE FILES.
        string sPath = "";
        //sPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/locker/");

        sPath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfilePath"]);

        //HttpFileCollection hfc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        HttpFileCollection hfc = strDocPath;

        // CHECK THE FILE COUNT.
        for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1; iCnt++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[iCnt];

            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // CHECK IF THE SELECTED FILE(S) ALREADY EXISTS IN FOLDER. (AVOID DUPLICATE)
                if (!File.Exists(sPath + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                {
                    // SAVE THE FILES IN THE FOLDER.
                    hpf.SaveAs(sPath + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    iUploadedCnt = iUploadedCnt + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // RETURN A MESSAGE (OPTIONAL).
        if (iUploadedCnt > 0)
        {
            return iUploadedCnt + " Files Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Upload Failed";
        }
    }
```

Cool. When i run the code and passed data to the swagger, I have two different issues:

1-The first issue is, let's say i created a docx file anywhere or in c:/ on my machine and passes the data as follows:

```
 {
    "szDescription": "Business Registration",
    "iRequirementTypeId": 30012,
    "szRequirementNumber": "BR3363347G",
    "szRequirementIssuer": "Environment Protection Agency",
    "szOrganization": "Blue Ocean Limited",
    "dIssuedate": "2014-02-09 00:00:00.000",
    "dExpirydate": "2018-02-09 00:00:00.000",
    "szSignedBy": "Somad",
    "szAttachedDocumentNo": "C:\Files\Doc3.docx",
    "szSubject": "Sub1",
    "iApplicationDetailsId": 01
    "iEmpId": 40021
}
```

I got an error saying: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
For this error, I know i am passing a wrong data somewhere, and i realized that it's at the 'szAttachedDocumentNo' after debugging the code. So I tried the following which my second issue:

2-Here i just passed the name of the document which is "Doc3.docx". All data have been saved to database that's not what i am looking for:

```
{
   "szDescription": "Business Registration",
   "iRequirementTypeId": 30012,
   "szRequirementNumber": "BR3363347G",
   "szRequirementIssuer": "Environment Protection Agency",
   "szOrganization": "Blue Ocean Limited",
   "dIssuedate": "2014-02-09 00:00:00.000",
   "dExpirydate": "2018-02-09 00:00:00.000",
   "szSignedBy": "Somad",
   "szAttachedDocumentNo": "Doc3.docx",
   "szSubject": "Sub1",
   "iApplicationDetailsId": 01
   "iEmpId": 40021
```

}

I just wnt a way to convert the doc3.docx to a string in the database, sorry in the table...

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Somad Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the path:

```
"C:\\Files\\Doc3.docx"
```

Your Json is also missing the comma at the end of the `iApplicationDetailsId` line, and `01` isn't a valid Json number.

Valid Json:

```
{
    "szDescription": "Business Registration",
    "iRequirementTypeId": 30012,
    "szRequirementNumber": "BR3363347G",
    "szRequirementIssuer": "Environment Protection Agency",
    "szOrganization": "Blue Ocean Limited",
    "dIssuedate": "2014-02-09 00:00:00.000",
    "dExpirydate": "2018-02-09 00:00:00.000",
    "szSignedBy": "Somad",
    "szAttachedDocumentNo": "C:\\Files\\Doc3.docx",
    "szSubject": "Sub1",
    "iApplicationDetailsId": 1,
    "iEmpId": 40021
}
```

Comment: Thanks stuartd. I'm now getting the file path in my table. Now how can i convert it to a pdf and save it to a shared file?

Comment: There are [lots of options for converting Word files to PDF](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert+word+document+to+pdf+c%23)